# SQLite dialect into Hibernate-Maven project

Tags: java, hibernate, sqlite

i am a java student and i have to do a small project. I have to use Maven and Hibernate ( no Spring frameworks). I use IntelliJ as IDE. The thing is that my teacher recomended me to use SQLite as RDBMS because its very simple, 1 file and there is no need to implement a server inside my app. ( i have no idea to do the last point). 
The problem is that when i try to do the "hibernate.cfg.xml " i have no way to configure it because of the lack of information. Seems there is no dialect supported from Hibernate and the info i could find on internet is outdated. Any idea on how i can configure it? Do i really need to use another RDBMS ?
there is a picture of my [project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsi9F.png)

this is my hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.sqlite.JDBC</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:sqlite://db/appiculturedb.sqlite3</property>
        <property name="connection.username"></property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>

        <!--        maping with xml-->
        <mapping resource="Bodega.hbm.xml" />

        <!--        maping with anotations-->
        <!--        <mapping class="com.stephane.Bodega" />     -->

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching for few days, i found that you can use SQLite with Hibernate 5 if you create your own dialect. You also can try to use someone else dialect wich may be risky or outdated. Check this [link](http://www.javaboss.it/en/hibernate-e-sqlite/) for more info.
For the moment, hibernate do not support oficially SQLite. Maybe in the future that will change.
If you are searching for an embedded database, you can use [H2](https://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) wich is supported by Hibernate and seems to be recommended by them.
You also have HSQLDB or Apache Derby.